# Tomcat realm for oauth2?

Tags: java, tomcat, oauth-2.0

I want to use tomcat's realm mechanism for authorization, but I want to allow users to either login directly (say `JDBCRealm`) or login via OAuth2 (say through LinkedIn). I found out that in principle, one could use `CombinedRealm` to combine two different methods of authentication, but I cannot find anything about any realm implementation for OAuth2.

PS: I am also open to completely different way to allow the dual authentication requirement.

Comment: I have this exact question.  Was JASPIC your solution, or did you come up with something more custom?

Comment: It was some time ago. I think I decided to choose a completely different path, i.e., did not really solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box implementation of an OAuth Realm for Tomcat. There is, however, a JASPIC adapter for Tomcat can be used for arbitrary authentication back-ends.

There is a [community-contributed back-end that provider OAuth2](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/jaspic.html#Philip_Green_II%27s_module_for_Google_OAuth_2).

Your mileage may vary ... greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the [Keycloak OIDC Tomcat adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_tomcat_adapter) We are using it and even extend it for different use cases, for instance: [Integrating ORDS with 3rd-party SSO](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/node/184)

Hope it helps,

Luis